# While loop is repeating one record?

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli, while-loop

[image] I have created while loop which is used to fetch record matching the word getting from URL. The variable is getting the word but while loop is repeating only one record don't know why? here is my code.

```
include_once('dbconnect.php');
$GetChR=isset($_REQUEST['authchar'])?$_REQUEST['authchar']:'';
 //get the function
include_once ('function.php');[![enter image description here][1]][1]
$page = (int) (!isset($_GET["page"]) ? 1 : $_GET["page"]);
$limit = 25;
$startpoint = ($page * $limit) - $limit;
//to make pagination
  $statement = " table2, table1 WHERE table1.col2 like '%$GetChR%'";
   echo '<div class="records round">';
   //show records
    $query = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT table2.col2 AS a,table1.col2 AS b,   table1.col1 AS c, table1.q_url AS d, table1.tags AS e FROM {$statement} LIMIT   {$startpoint} , {$limit}");
     while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($query)) 
     {
         $input='';
        //$Authorname =$row['a'];
        $url = "http://$_SERVER[HTTP_HOST]$_SERVER[REQUEST_URI]";
        $url=explode('/',$url);
        echo '<div class="record round">'; $input .='<a   href="http://localhost/quotes/'.$url[5].'/'.$row['d'].'.html">';
        echo $input .=$row['b'];echo'</a>';echo '</div>';

         // $count++;  
        }
        echo'</div>';

     echo pagination($statement,$limit,$page);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These are the main issues with your code:

1. You're not joining your tables. There's no condition or join statement that describes how `table1` and `table2` are to be linked. Results are unpredictable, but would need to see your data to be sure if this is what causes the repeated record.
2. You're creating a massive SQL injection risk by dumping a request parameter straight into your query. Use prepared statements instead.

Comment: in sql the result is right but only here it is not getting.

Comment: When you're trying in SQL, do you use exactly the same query? With no join statement or condition? If you echo your PHP-created query, will that exact same query create correct results when executed directly on the database?

Comment: can you please suggest me join query?

Comment: bro I tried again and I found that there is a mistake in my query can you please suggest me join query?

Comment: I don't know the relation between your tables. What's columns are used as primary and foreign keys? Since you don't seem to be using any data from `table2`, why not leave it out? Also, I'm not your bro.

Comment: yes bor ..There is no use of table 2 here can make changes to get the required record. row[a] is not required, row[b] is the real quotes i need to fetch row[d] is slug for url